# C#: How do your Filter and Order LINQ query

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework, linq

have a WinForms application connected to a Movies SQL Server database via Entity Framework (EF 6).

I have the following SQL which I'm attempting to convert into a LINQ query

```
SELECT m.title,f.path,f.size FROM movie m, MovieLinkFile mlf, "file" f
WHERE m.id = mlf.movieId AND mlf.fileId = f.id 
AND f.path like 'M%'
ORDER BY f.size
```

returns

> 12345, M\PathTo\Best movie 2022\Best move.mkv,1.54 GB, 720p

size is type Varchar(max)

In the database there are 3 tables:

```
Movies (id, Title, Year, IMDB,etc)
MoviesLinkFiles (id, MovieId, FileId)
Files (id, path, size, etc)
```

This will allow me to select  the movies that have more than one file starting with drive M?

```
var Movies = context.movies.AsQueryable()
    .Where(m => m.files.Count(file => file.path.StartsWith("M:\\")) > 1)
    .OrderBy(movie => movie.title);
```

How do I write the LINQ statement in C# so

```
file.path.StartsWith("M:\\")
```

AND

```
OrderBy (file.size)?
```

In this example I don't need to count files

My attempt errors

```
var Movies = context.movies.AsQueryable()
    .Where(m => m.files.Any(file => file.path.StartsWith("M:\\")))
    .OrderBy(movie => movie.files.Any(f => f.size) );
```

> Error CS1662  Cannot convert lambda expression to intended delegate type because some of the return types in the block are not implicitly convertible to the delegate return type

Comment: .Any() returns a boolean.

Comment: Your SQL at top doesn't match table definitions. Maybe restate your question.

Comment: Removing .Any() gives 
`Error CS1955 Non-invocable member 'movie.files' cannot be used like a method.`

Comment: @Holly, what are you trying to do? Your SQL and structures and also query have no correlation.

Comment: Please see edit the SQL now links the 3 tables I'm trying to return all movies but order by file size

Comment: Taking a query that works well in SQL and rewriting it for linq is a step backwards. EF will let you send raw SQL to the server. If you have something even remotely complicated and you already have the SQL, use that ability.

Comment: Since a movie can have multiple files, are you trying to order by the maximum file size, the average file size, the sum of all the file sizes, or something else?

Comment: Hmm... except maybe in this case. Who taught you the `FROM A,B` join syntax? It's been obsolete for _**30 years**_ now. No one should be using it anymore.

Comment: I'm curious how you even do ".Where(m => m.files" when, according to your table structure and SQL query, there is no direct foreign key relationship between Movies and Files.

Comment: @BrianM: The MovieLinkFiles table would serve as a many-to-many mapping, right?

Comment: @StriplingWarrior The MovieLinkFiles table serves as  One Movie-to-Many Files e.g. Movie.mkv,Movie.dvd or Part1 & Part2

Comment: You should have shown the class model from the outset. It's not obvious that you have a many-to-many relationship with a hidden junction class. Also use a tag for the exact EF version you're using. Also, make clear if you want the same output as the SQL statement, i.e. with duplicated movies in the result set. The LINQ query doesn't do that, making it unclear what sorting by size actually means.

Comment: I took @JoelCoehoorn advise and created a stored procedure on the database I was then able to call it and pass a FilePath parameter returning and array of movie objects

Thanx for your help

Answer (score -1):

I think that you looking for something like this:

```cs
var result = (from movie in context.Movies
             join movielink in context.MoviesLinkFiles
               on movie.id equals movielink.MovieId
             join file in context.Files
               on file.id equals movielink.FileId
             where path.StartWith("M:\\")
             orderby file.size asscending
             select new { movie.Title, movie.Year, movie.Imbd, file.path, file.size }).ToList();
```

Comment: `Contains()` will create a poor execution plan. Since it's equivalent to `LIKE '%key%'` instead of `LIKE 'key%'` it breaks any chance of using an index for that filter.

Comment: @JoelCoehoorn you're right here. Must be StartWith function.

Comment: There are navigation properties., don't regress into `join` statements.

Comment: I couldn't get this to work using LINQ taking this as a starting point I tried multiple ways I couldn't  access Files properties